# How to extend a dictionary with integers

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2}

a[key].extend(1,0)

print(a)

{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2,1,0}
```

I wish to used extend to do that

I tried using the following:

```
a = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
for key in a:
   a[key].append([1],[0])
```

But I am getting an error

Comment: You cannot extend integers. use a dict of lists: `di = {"a" : [1] }` can be extended : `di["a"].extend( [4,5,6])` - and append only ever accents one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `append` to an integer, which isn't going to work. If your values were lists it would work. For example:

```
>>> a = { "a" : [1], "b" : [2] }
>>> for key in a:
...   a[key].extend([1,0])
...
```

Would give you:

```
>>> a
{'a': [1, 1, 0], 'b': [2, 1, 0]}
```

(I'm using `extend` rather than `append` here because we are trying to add multiple values.)

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what i wanted to achieve